# C++: Can't reassign a null-initialized object pointer by passing to a finder function

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class IntObj {
  public:
    int num;
    IntObj(int num): num(num) {}
};

bool findNum(int num, IntObj* dst, std::vector<IntObj*> intobjs) {
    for(int i=0; i<(int)intobjs.size(); i++) {
        if (intobjs[i]->num==5) {
            dst = intobjs[i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<IntObj*> intobjs;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        IntObj* io = new IntObj(i);
        intobjs.push_back(io);
    }
    IntObj* ioptr = NULL;
    findNum(5, ioptr, intobjs);

    std::cout<<ioptr<<std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

This is a test program to reproduce my error for a bigger program. Even when findNum function enters the if statement dst won't change from NULL to intobjs[i].

I am doing this because I want to do two things from function call:
1. find out if object was found in the list
2. store the object to dst pointer if it was found

Why does this not reassign the pointer variable? Also, please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: C++ is pass-by-value. If you need pass-by-reference, use a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dst` *does* change but `ioptr` does not. These are two different variables that have two values, albeit `dst` is at first set to the value of `ioptr`.

You need to pass it by reference to change `ioptr` as well:

```
bool findNum(int num, IntObj*& dst, std::vector<IntObj*> intobjs)
```

Comment: ahhh thank you I never thought of passing a pointer by reference just objects.